# Curvature tensor and Levi-Civita connection

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature, connections

Assuming $M$ is a Riemannian manifold and $p$ is a point on $M$, consider a local orthonormal frame around $p$ denoted by $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$. Suppose that we are given the components $R_{ijk} = R(e_i,e_j)e_k$ for every $1 \leq i,j,k\leq n$. The question is whether there exists a formula for $\nabla_{e_i}e_j$ in terms of $R_{ijk}$ alone?

Comment: Recall that the curvature $F$ of a connection $\nabla$ is defined by $\nabla^2 s=F\wedge s$. So why would you expect that $\nabla$ itself can be derived from $\nabla^2$? I would be quite confident in saying that this is, in general, impossible.

Comment: Since the formula for the curvature contains partial derivatives of $\nabla_{e_i}e_j$ there is no reason to believe there could be a formula. In general, a system of partial differential equations cannot be solved using a formula. Beyond that, if you write out the equations, you'll find that there are more equations than unknown functions. This indicates that in general there are no solutions, formula or not.

Comment: Following up on Didier's comment under my answer: Are you asking whether a Levi-Civita connection can be recovered from its curvature tensor? If so, the answer is no. If not, from exactly what data are you trying to reconstruct the curvature? Notice that different orthonormal frames $(E_i)$ on a given metric can have different connection coefficients $c_{ij}^k$ (i.e., functions characterized by $\nabla_{E_i} E_j = c_{ij}^k E_k$), hence different expressions $c_{ij}^k E_k$.

Answer (score 1):

In general this isn't possible.

For $n = 2$, consider the metric $$g = e^{2 \lambda(x, y)} (dx^2 + dy^2)$$ for some function $\lambda$. (In fact, every surface metric can be locally written this way, and we call $(x, y)$ *isothermal coordinates* for $g$.) Then,
$$(E_1, E_2) := (e^{-\lambda} \partial_x, e^{-\lambda} \partial_y)$$ is an orthonormal frame. Computing gives that the Levi-Civita connection $\nabla$ of $g$ is characterized by
$$\nabla_{E_1} E_1 = -\lambda_y e^{-\lambda} E_2, \qquad
\nabla_{E_1} E_2 =  \lambda_y e^{-\lambda} E_1, \qquad
\nabla_{E_2} E_1 =  \lambda_x e^{-\lambda} E_2, \qquad
\nabla_{E_2} E_2 = -\lambda_x e^{-\lambda} E_1 ,$$
and the curvature components $R_{ijk}$ with respect to $(E_1, E_2)$ are determined by
$$R_{1212} = -e^{-2 \lambda} \Delta \lambda ,$$
where $\Delta$ is the Laplacian operator, $\Delta := \nabla^i \nabla_i$.

So if we define a metric $g$ by picking a nonconstant harmonic function $\lambda$ (i.e., one satisfying $\Delta \lambda = 0$), then $g$ and the flat metric $\bar g = dx^2 + dy^2$ have the same curvature, $R = 0$, but different connections $\nabla$.

Comment: I don't get your point. A Riemannian manifold is flat if and only if it is locally isometric to the Euclidean space, and in this case, its Levi-Civita connection is the one induced by this local isometry, so in a sense it is that of $\Bbb R^n$. It's not because you look at it in a different coordinates system that it is not the same.

Comment: It's true that the connections are related by a local isometry, but that's not germane to what o.p.'s question seems to be, i.e., whether you can recover $\nabla$ from $R^\nabla$. The computation shows that the map $\nabla \mapsto R^\nabla$ is not injective, hence not invertible. If you see another reasonable interpretation of the question, I would be happy to learn what it is, not least so that o.p. can then clarify their intent.

Comment: Right, now I see your point, thanks